# Thoughts on upgrade to 1.14

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade

Looking for thoughts if I should go to 13.1 before going to 14.0.1 on an upgrade from 13.0.1?

EDIT: My question more specifically. Should I bother into copy in the 1.13.1 files, then do the php scripts, then run the 1.14 files?

Comment: oh that really does depend on your needs and current system. Some more information may help but you may find answers are a bit to heavy on the personal opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Magento database upgrades are cumulative, which means that all upcoming database upgrades also contain previous upgrades. So from database perspective there's no reason to make pit-stops at 1.13.1.

As of themes, I don't know. I don't think your theme gets any better when you make incremental upgrades; all your core files get overwritten anyway and the only thing you achieve doing incremental upgrade is that you have to test you theme and functionality twice.

Quite frankly I've never done incremental upgrades as it's pretty much total waste of time and effort. I always let Magento upgrade database to latest version (it might take several hours, depending how outdated your old version is) and after that I go through theme files and e-mail templates. I don't trust people who recommend doing incremental upgrade; they're probably just trying to sell you development hours you really don't need.

Comment: The upgrade to 1.13 required PHP scripts to be run, so how do you get around not doing the incremental upgrade?

Comment: I haven't done upgrade to 1.14 myself, but I'm pretty sure that should it have such a script, it would work just as well on 1.13. Cumulative upgrade automatically does all the increments needed to get to 1.14.

Comment: Pronto, but after the upgrade from 1.12 you have to run the URL script in the Shell directory for 1.13. My question is do I need to do this before going to 1.14